# Autohotkey fails to recognize image under resolution change

Tags: autohotkey, image-recognition

I have created an autohotkey scripts which automates a manual process by launching an application and clicking on the script mentioned icons. The script is working fine on one computer which having higher resoultion but fails to execute on other computer with different resoultion. Do you have any suggestions to workout in other way. This app doesn't have any keyboard shortcuts and only executes on mouse clicks. I hope there will be an anwer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**::: Explaining the problem :::** Please read to understand the problem.

Lets start off simple you create the autohotkey script on COMPUTER_A, you print_screen/capture all your images & resize them on COMPUTER_A, however when you transfer your files to COMPUTER_B image_search does not find matchs as well or at all, why is this ?

Well COMPUTER_A and COMPUTER_B are two totally different computers, the problem comes cause with two different computers each have different COLOR TEMPLATES installed on them, if you copy the color template from COMPUTER_A onto COMPUTER_B or any computer.  Overall problem is different color templates does not allow image_search to find a match pixel by pixel cause the varying difference between the two different computers.  Thats why its best to copy color template from computer_A to another computer to allow image search to work properly.

**::: Finding the COLOR Template :::**

On Win7 --> Control Panel --> Color Management --> Mine was easy to find cause it is the color template that came with my computer monitor, however yours might take a little more work in finding.  ICC profiles are generally printers, ICM profiles are display drivers/color templates for you computer screen.  Once you find your display profile currently in use on COMPUTER_A find it on your computer storage & copy it to your autohotkey direction for easy access in the future so it can be copied with your autohotkey script to computer_B or computer_Z later.  Right Click on the ICM once copied to computer_B and click install & its possible you may need to restart the computer for all changes to take affect.

**::: Results :::**

Once the color template from computer_A is installed on another computer image_search should work exactly how it does on computer_A, i've personally tested the results on 6 different computers from XP, Vista & Win7, always had a 100% success rate which i believe makes this a universal solution/fix to the image_search problem with other computers.

I do caution those few people who have trouble with this to have patience & do you fair share of research into "windows color profiles" to make this solution work for you, i just foresee someone accidently finding/copying the wrong ICM/ICC profile.  Also to be warned if someone installs photography software/development software like adobe photoshop/multimedia/development software sometimes they come with their own ICM/ICC profiles and could overright the existing ones causing image_search to again become a problem.  Just reinstall the  default ICC/ICM profile again to fix that problem.

**::: CONCLUSION :::**

I hope this was helpful to someone, sorry for all the writing but i thought it best to share my complete findings with you all since it can get complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Most Apps Have Alt Shortcuts, have you tried them? also you may try re-adjusting mouse click x,y as per resoulution

Comment: My bad..It doesn't have alt shortcuts..Can you give me an example how can we adjust mouse clicks based on resoultion. Here I find error as "Image not found".

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I once solved it.. In the beginning I ask the user to capture the mouse position of each icon, and store these coordinates for later use.

```
Hotkey, LButton, off ; Make sure that the Left Mouse button inactivator is turned Off

Lbutton:: ; Disable the Left Mouse Button

SplashImage , %A_ScriptDir%/Images/YourScreenShot.jpg,,, Screen shot, Icons     ;   Show Screenshot of what the user needs to do
SoundBeep 1000, 300 ; wake up user


SplashTextOn, 200, 100, Script Preparations, Please Click on Icon1. ; Show new instructions to the user
WinMove, Script Preparations,, (A_ScreenWidth/2)-150, (A_ScreenHeight/2)-200 ; Move the text instructions window with the name "Script Preparations" 150 pixels right of the center of the screen and 200 pixels up
SoundBeep 600, 300 ; Wake up user
; Here the left mouse button will temporarily be disabled (to prevent actions)
Hotkey, LButton, on ; Turn Left Mouse Button OFF, to capture the Mouse click
KeyWait, LButton, D ; Wait for LeftMouseButton click Down
MouseGetPos, xpos1 ,ypos1 ; Store the position where the mouse was clicked (Icon1)
```

Repeat this for all icons used.

Then if you want to click on icon1 use:

```
MouseClick, left, %xpos1% ,%ypos1% ; Perform the mouse click on the captured mouse location
```

Comment: You could also use the script above to just capture the "first" and "last" icon and calculate the position of the other icons in between. This assumes that all icons are in the same position (no user modified  menu bars). To be sure, I would maximize the window before capturing the positions and in your workflow loop add a winmaximize every time the loop starts, just to be sure that the user has not changed the window position.